# Validar si un integer tiene un valor nulo

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Trabajo con C#, Visual Studio 2019

Tengo un método de filtros condicionales tengo un problema uno de los parámetros recibe un valor `int` si no he puesto un valor debo mandarle un nulo, pero los tipos `int` no admiten nulos por lo que se trabaja con `HasValue` y `Value` pero no puedo implementarlo.

```
var filter = new CriteriaOrdenVenta()
        {
            ClienteId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtClienteId.Text) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtClienteId.Text),
            Codigo = txtCodigo.Text,
            FechaEmision = chkFechaEmision.Checked ? (DateTime?)dtpFechaEmision.Value : null,
            FechaCaducidad = chkFechaCaducidad.Checked ? (DateTime?)dtpFechaCaducidad.Value : null,
        };
```

¿Como debo implementar correctamente en esta linea de código?

```
ClienteId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtClienteId.Text) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtClienteId.Text),
```

Clase Criteria

```
public class CriteriaOrdenVenta
{
    public int? ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaEmision { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaCaducidad { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: var o dynamic podria ser una solución en tu caso ya que los ints son typo non-nullable, en cambio si es var/dynamic como acepta cualquier valor

Comment: Que error te lanza?

Comment: No lanza ni un error debería de enviarle algo como esto (!filter.ClienteId.HasValue || ov.ClienteId.Equals(filter.ClienteId.Value))

Comment: Hola. Si clientId es obligatorio, te recomiendo evaluar antes `string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtClienteId.Text)` y si lo es, elevar una excepción de tipo `ArgumentException` o `ArgumentNullException`. No tiene sentido dejar continuar si un campo requerido no está informado

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra ClienteId no es obligatorio, es uno mas de los filtros condicionales que puede ir como no, mi problema es como mandarle vacío si es que no le mando ClienteId el cual es de tipo int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es esto:

```
ClienteId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtClienteId.Text) ? (int ?)null : Convert.ToInt32(txtClienteId.Text);
```

Tan sólo que hay que tener cuidado porque si el texto no viene validado como numérico podría lanzar una excepción al intentar convertirlo.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias JuanRu fue mi solución.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar TryParse, para que solo se asigne el valor cuando se pueda convertir:

```
//C#7
if (int.TryParse(txtClienteId.Text, out var result))
{
     filter.ClienteId = result;
}
```